# It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to build a Docker image and run a container for my sample ASP.NET Core 3.1 app and am seeing

> It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs

when I run the command

`docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 ppi`

My Dockerfile is simple:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
COPY publish/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "sampleapp.dll"]
```

and I am pre-building my app into the `publish` folder. My folder structure looks as follows:

```
root/
  source/
    SampleApp.csproj
    appsettings.json
    Startup.cs
    Program.cs
  publish/
    SampleApp.dll
    SampleApp.exe
    appsettings.json
    SampleApp.deps.json
    SampleApp.runtimeconfig.json
    web.config
  Dockerfile
  SampleApp.sln
```

I created the image using the following command

`docker build -t ppi`

There are no issues with my sample app, as I'm able to launch it locally with the following command

`dotnet publish/sampleapp.dll`

What am I missing here? I've been working off of the following tutorials:

1. [Building .NET Docker Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
2. [dotnet-docket/samples/aspnetapp](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/samples/aspnetapp)

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core 3.1 SDK?

Comment: To expand on the comment from @John, the SDK is not the same as the redist (what users have installed).  Two different things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## summary answer:

This image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1` is a .NET Runtime.

The recommended way of creating a docker image is to copy the code inside a dotnet sdk image.
And fire all the build commands inside the docker image.

Once done. You copy only the publish folder to a dotnet runtime image (the one you are using).

If you are using visual studio; use the Add Docker Support option to generate a Dockerfile. And everything should work like a charm.

The error message is a little cryptic in saying that not all the files are present for running the application.

Your Dockerfile should look like below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myaspnetapp.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./myaspnetapp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "myaspnetapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myaspnetapp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myaspnetapp.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but did not want to build the app using the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster image. I discovered the shell running in the Linux container (bash) is case sensitive.

In your Dockerfile, change `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "sampleapp.dll"]` to `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleApp.dll"]`.

On Windows 10 either command will work since the shell there is case insensitive.

"Works on my machine..." anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error on Windows, when trying to run the Published version, ie just trying to use the runtime, not the sdk.

The solution for me was to change this:

```
dotnet sample
```

to this:

```
dotnet sample.dll
```